# Get error struct has no member named when build pjsip with openh264?

Tags: pjsip, openh264

I want to build Voip app on Android with video support, so I build pjsip 2.4 with openh264 base on following link: 
https://trac.pjsip.org/repos/wiki/Getting-Started/Android

I built openh264 and configure success with pjsip:

> Using OpenH264 prefix... /Users/me/openh264-1.0.0/android
>   checking OpenH264 availability... ok
>   Using libyuv prefix... /Users/me/libyuv-android/jni
>   checking for I420Scale in -lyuv... yes

But when make pjsip, I get error:

> ../src/pjmedia-codec/openh264.cpp: In function 'pj_status_t oh264_codec_open(pjmedia_vid_codec*, pjmedia_vid_codec_param*)':
>   ../src/pjmedia-codec/openh264.cpp:474:10: error: 'SEncParamExt' has no member named 'iInputCsp'
>        eprm.iInputCsp   = videoFormatI420;

I see struct SEncParamExt in code_app_def.h dont have member iInputCsp, but openh264.cpp in pjsip used it?
How I can fix it?
Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 1):

this may related some version problem, the older version of openh264 has that variable but later versions this is removed.

https://github.com/cisco/openh264/issues/2132